# traverse Array of Objects of mixed Types

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am trying something really easy (at least in ObjC).

I would like to traverse a Collection - lets say an Array  of Strings & Subarrays, print all Strings and call the function recursively to traverse any subarrays.

I tried something like this:

```
func traverseCollection<T : Sequence>(collection: T)
{
    var generator = collection.generate()
    while let item = generator.next()
    {
        if let collectionItem = item as? Collection
        {
            traverseCollection(collectionItem)
        }
        else
        {
            println("item:", item)
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting an Error for trying to downcast item:

cannot downcast from 'T.GeneratorType.Element' to non-@objc protocol type 'Collection'
        if let collectionItem = item as? Collection

A less generic variant fails also with an compilation error:

```
func traverseArray(array: Array<Any>)
{
       for item : Any in array
       {
            if let collectionItem = item as? Array<Any>
            {
                traverseArray(collectionItem)
            }
            else
            {
                println("item:", item)
            }
       }
}
```

That one either crashes  playground or fails to compile:

```
Instruction does not dominate all uses!
  %10 = bitcast %swift.opaque* %9 to %Sq.20*, !dbg !235
  %3 = ptrtoint %Sq.20* %10 to i32, !dbg !232
Instruction does not dominate all uses!
  %T = load %swift.type** %3, align 4
  %4 = bitcast %swift.type* %T to i8*, !dbg !232
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
```

I think I am trying it to solve the wrong way but I can't figure out how to that one in Swift.Would be nice if anybody could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a dynamic solution instead of recursive one, regarding I would not like to take a risk to overflow the stack with the non-deterministic number of recursive calls.

```
func printArray(array: Array<AnyObject>) -> () {
    var dynamicCollection: Array<AnyObject> = array
    dynamicCollection.unshare()
    do {
        let firstObject: AnyObject = dynamicCollection[0]
        if let myString: String = firstObject as? String {
            println(myString)
        } else if let myArray: Array<AnyObject> = firstObject as? Array {
            dynamicCollection += myArray
        }
        dynamicCollection.removeAtIndex(0)
    } while dynamicCollection.count > 0
}
```

---

that was my test array, it holds only `String` and another `Array` objects only:

```
let myArray : Array<AnyObject> = ["string1", ["subString1", "subString2"], ["moreSubString1"], "string2", [["deepSubString1", "deepSubString2"], "justSubString1"]]
```

and the result looks like this on my console:

```
string1
string2
subString1
subString2
moreSubString1
justSubString1
deepSubString1
deepSubString2
```

Comment: I like the solution and it works indeed for my problem. Still have no clue why my recursive approach fails. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all the second example you have is clearly a compiler bug, please report it at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com).

This is not a "pure" swift solution but it works:

```
import Foundation
var array : NSArray = [1, 2, [3, 4]]

func printElements(array: NSArray) {
    for item : AnyObject in array {
        if let itemArray = item as? NSArray {
            printElements(itemArray)
        } else {
            println("\(item)")
        }
    }
}

printElements(array)
```